# Likelihood ratio test with zero inflated models to check overdispersion

Tags: maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data, zero-inflation

I am trying to compare ZIP and ZINB models and see if there is an overdispersion. They have the same parameters except alpha. I am wondering if it is correct to use Likelihood ratio test, the same way like we do this with poisson and negbin models. Will critical value still have 1 df? (because of alpha as a difference).

And I would like to know - is it possible to compare ZIP and ZINB models with different parameters (not nested) with this test?

Answer (score 3):

ZIP and ZINB are nested in the same way that Poisson and Negative Binomial are nested. You get the former for $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ or $\theta \rightarrow \infty$ (depending on the preferred notation). Thus, the parameter is on the boundary of the parameter space under the null hypothesis and hence the null distribution is somewhat non-standard and the p-value can be halved.

The intuition behind this is that usually the likelihood ratio test is two-sided whereas only a one-sided alternative is assessed here. Hence the halving of the p-value.

Remark from my personal experience: If you get a $\theta$ beyond 10 or 20, it is pretty close to infinity, leading to virtually the same results as a Poisson model. Of course, this is no formal significance test but often useful as a rule of thumb.